# Making a VBA API Request with Auth and 2 Headers?

Tags: python, vba, api, https, request

I have the following code in Python and want to move the request over to VBA. How do I write this in VBA?

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v1/data/order_book_snapshots.v1/exchanges/drbt/option/btc26jun2010000c/snapshots/full?" \
      "start_time=2020-05-29T17:33:00.000000Z&end_time=2020-05-29T17:33:10.000000000Z"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'x-api-key': '123456'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
result = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: There are plenty of posts here covering how to make a GET request from VBA. Please take a look at some of those.

Comment: Yes, for simple GET requests I see. But I don't see support for examples with headers

Comment: eg - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645875/msxml2-xmlhttp-fails-to-send-request-cookie-header

Comment: @TimWilliams please see my response and question in comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub testAPI()
Dim http As Object
Dim JSON As Object


Dim pm As Worksheet
Set pm = Sheets("Params")

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "GET", ("https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v1/data/order_book_snapshots.v1/exchanges/drbt/option/btc26jun209000p/snapshots/full?start_time=2020-05-29T17:33:00.000Z&end_time=2020-05-29T17:33:30.0Z"), False
http.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
http.SetRequestHeader "x-api-key", "1234"

http.Send
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.ResponseText)

pm.Cells(2, 8).Value = JSON("data")(1)("asks")(1)("price")


End Sub
```

Comment: @TimWilliams when I run the above I get "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument". I think I am calling the correct parsed Json format? The result format is given here: https://docs.kaiko.com/#order-book-snapshots-full

Comment: "asks" will be parsed to a VBA collection object: you can't assign a collection to a cell value.  `pm.Cells(2, 8).Value = JSON("data")(1)("asks")(1)("amount")` (for example) should work assuming you got the expected response.

Comment: When I use pm.Cells(2, 8).Value = JSON("data")(1)("asks")(1)("amount") it still gives "invalid Procedure Call or Argument". I put JSON, from the row above it, in the Expression-Watchlist. When I put a breakpoint at the pm.Cells(2,8).Value row I see data in the Watchlist for Item4 but there is nothing to expand. Is that a contributing issue?

Comment: I can't see the actual response, so it's difficult for me to say what the problem might be.  Are you using this library to parse the JSON - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON  ?

Comment: Yes, I am using that library to parse the JSON

Comment: That should work based on the sample response on the API page.